# Do UEFI Mobos have beep codes?

Tags: uefi

My PC mobo has legacy BIOS however I am curious to know  if the UEFI Mobos  have beep codes like BIOS. 
Do they generate beep codes for any crucial failures like missing RAM or graphics etc?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beep codes are a per-manufacturer decision and system. There is nothing about UEFI specifically which prevents or does not support beep codes.